Help to solve 74LS85 comparator
I am working on a 4-bit comparator problem using a 74LS85 chip. I have two 4-bit binary inputs, A and B, and I am trying to determine the output signals (A = B, A > B, A < B) based on the timing diagram.
Here is the datasheet for it https://www.uni-kl.de/elektronik-lager/417661
Here is the image of the timing diagram:

Can someone explain how to interpret the timing and correctly determine the output signals?

In the datasheet from the truth table you can try to answer the question.
for example: A3 > B3 -> output A>B is H, A = B is L and A < B is L and so on.

As the datasheet specifies, A is a 4-bit number where A3 is the MSB and A0 is the LSB.  Starting from the left of the timing diagram, ignore the section where all A signals are red.  In the 1st square where all A signals are black, the 4-bit binary value is 1001, which corresponds to decimal value 9.
The same applies to the B signals.  B is 0100, which is decimal 4.  Since 9 is greater than 4, A>B, so the A>B output is high (H), and the other 2 outputs are low.
You can apply the same procedure to determine the 3 outputs for the remaining times.
Alternately, you can use the TRUTH TABLE in the datasheet to determine the outputs based on the inputs.  Looking at the MSB's only, A3=1 and B3=0.  Since 1>0, this means A3>B3, therefore the A>B output is high (H).  This corresponds to the top row in the table.  In this case, there is no reason to even evaluate the remaining bits in A and B.

The comparator table is very "expressive".
Here is a simulation of the circuit (sample with B=[0,1] ) with an enlarged part of data.
Made with microcap v12

Enlarged view

Complete view only with input AeqB=1

NB: you have 2 more views simulations ...
